# Mui steplabel color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the `steplabel` color of my mui `stepper` to be grayed for the completed steps. And i want to make that in the theme itslef.

```
MuiStepLabel: {
    styleOverrides: {
      completed: {
        color: "grey",
      },
    },
  },



<Stepper activeStep={0} orientation="vertical">

        return (
          <Step key={id} completed={isCompleted}>
            <StepLabel icon={<StepIcon icon={isCompleted ? <CheckCircle /> : <CircleOutlined />} />}>
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                {startTime}-{endTime} 
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="caption">{description}</Typography>
            </StepLabel>
          </Step>
        );
      })}
    </Stepper>
```